# Where is the Excel export option in DBeaver Community Edition

Tags: excel, dbeaver

Am using DBeaver 6.3.4 Community Edition and it doesn't show XLSX ( Excel) option when Data Export feature is selected as in the screenshot. This excel option appeared in my Trial version of Enterprise Ed.

Please help me enable/install this excel option or does Community Ed support at all?

[image]

Comment: Menu **Help** / **Install New Software** / **Work with**  `https://dbeaver.io/update/office/latest/`

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Excel export option is available only in Enterprise edition which is a Licensed version also while Community edition is for free.

Comment: Excel export also works for the community edition (CE) - see my answer below (or above :))

Answer (score 32):

Excel export also works for the community edition (CE). Tested with Version 7.3.2.202101032114. How-to (via [Google "dbeaver excel"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dbeaver%20excel)):

- https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Extension-Office
- https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Optional-extensions#office-integration
- http://ewaldertl.blogspot.com/2019/08/exporting-database-as-excel-sheet-from.html

An alternative to "Export data ...." is to select the cells to be exported in the result grid and the right click -> Open with -> Excel.

Comment: Perfect, first link provide a step-by-step process. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to go on "HELP" then "Install new software" and choose DBeaver Office Integration in "Work With". Install it and now you can select format XLSX to export data

[View of Install window of DBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsPbC.png)